# How is jsf dialog selected?

Tags: java, jsf, alfresco

I am working with Alfresco 4.2.3 in the explorer UI.

I am seeing a bug in a custom workflow task. More specifically when attempting to delete a resource from the Resource panel the wrong dialog config is selected and the resource/doc is not deleted.

The Dialog Config looks like so:

```
         <!-- Definition of the delete content dialog -->
     <dialog name="deleteFile" page="/jsp/dialog/delete.jsp" managed-bean="DeleteContentDialog" 
             icon="/images/icons/delete_large.gif" title-id="delete_file" 
             description-id="delete_file_info" />

     <dialog name="deleteFileAssoc" page="/jsp/dialog/delete.jsp" managed-bean="DeleteContentAssociationDialog" 
             icon="/images/icons/delete_large.gif" title-id="delete_file" 
             description-id="delete_file_assoc_info" />
```

The delete.jsp is as follows:

```
<h:outputText value="#{DialogManager.bean.confirmMessage}" styleClass="mainSubTitle" />
```

From debugging DialogManager.setCurrentDialog(DialogConfig config) I can see the DialogConfig is not correct. The deleteFileAssoc config is selected when it should select the deleteFile config.
I do not understand how the dialog config is selected. Please, JSF pros could explain how the DialogConfig is selected?

Note: Here is the Alfresco Wiki on the Dialog Framework. It got me this far now i'm stuck. https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Dialog_Framework#Dialog_Beans

Answer (score 0):

I searched through the code for the outcome dialog:deleteFileAssoc, witch is always prefixed with "dialog" when calling a dialog. This led me to the managed bean that calls the Navigation Handler and passes the outcome. Now I can see how the dialog is selected.

```
            fc.getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(fc, null, "dialog:deleteFileAssoc");
```

I'm still a novice but it seems that Outcomes in jsf can lead you through the code enough to figure out whats going on.